# Django Model does not exist error When accessing tabel from admin Panel

Tags: django, database, backend, digital-ocean, django-migrations

Ok so I was working on a project locally and then I followed a guide https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/deploy-django-to-digitalocean-app-platform in order to deploy on digital ocean and i did successfully, However; When I open the Django admin panel and try to access my tables, some of the tables open up just fine while two other tables give the following error as illustrated.[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPIqR.jpg),[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWJOE.jpg).
After hours and hours of searching questions here I reached a conclusion that something is wrong with the migrations. Regardless of how much I tried I failed to make it work.

I will provide the Logs maybe it helps you out more.

```
10.244.3.92 - - [10/Dec/2021:22:08:06 +0000] "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3912 "https://scheduler-live-rcfr9.ondigitalocean.app/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:06] Not Found: /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:06] 10.244.3.92 - - [10/Dec/2021:22:08:06 +0000] "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3906 "https://scheduler-live-rcfr9.ondigitalocean.app/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] Internal Server Error: /admin/myapi/schedule/
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] Traceback (most recent call last):
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column myapi_schedule.Start_Time does not exist
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] LINE 1: ...."Start_Date", "myapi_schedule"."Products_Array", "myapi_sch...
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08]                                                              ^
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "myapi_schedule.Start_Date".
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column myapi_schedule.Start_Time does not exist
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] LINE 1: ...."Start_Date", "myapi_schedule"."Products_Array", "myapi_sch...
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08]                                                              ^
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "myapi_schedule.Start_Date".
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] 
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:08] 10.244.3.92 - - [10/Dec/2021:22:08:08 +0000] "GET /admin/myapi/schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 500 148843 "https://scheduler-live-rcfr9.ondigitalocean.app/admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:28] 10.244.3.92 - - [10/Dec/2021:22:08:28 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7283 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36"
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:29] Internal Server Error: /admin/myapi/product/
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:29] Traceback (most recent call last):
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:29]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:29]     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:29] psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "myapi_product" does not exist
[scheduler-live] [2021-12-10 22:08:29] LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "myapi_product"
```

EDIT:
python manage.py showmigrations [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK9Vd.jpg)

[Updated show migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKRVH.jpg)

Comment: This is going to surprise you, but I think it's an issue with migrations. :) Can you post the output of `./manage.py showmigrations` so we can see which ones are applied?

Comment: @NickODell I know it is and i tried several commands related and i failed miserably. i updated the question with showmigrations output. The frustrating this is that locally i dont have this issue on my pc. but on digital ocean server it gives an error.

Comment: @NickODell i added the show migrations

Comment: Well, can you show all of the migrations? That screenshot is not complete.

Comment: Done sorry for any inconvenience @NickODell

Comment: You should show the django's error. this one is from the database.